# Reading a file using FileInputStream vs URLConnection

Tags: java, performance, urlconnection, fileinputstream

I have a piece of code that retrieves a file either from a remote server or from the local disk.

I understand that `URLConnection` can handle both cases, so I was wondering if there was any performance advantage if I used `FileInputStream` to read the local file rather than just handing it off to `URLConnection` to read from disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no performance advantage to using `FileInputStream` over a `URLConnection` (well, unless you're counting the milliseconds of a handful of extra method calls).

Reading a file via a `file://` URL eventually gets you a [`FileURLConnection`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/net/www/protocol/file/FileURLConnection.java) (note that this is not part of the official Java library spec, just the Sun-based JREs).  If you look at the code, you'll see that it's creating a `FileInputStream` to work with the file on disk.  So other than walking a few layers further down in the stack, the code ends up exactly the same.

The reason why you'd want to use a `FileInputStream` directly is for clarity of your code.  Turning a file path into a URL is a little ugly, and it'd be confusing to do it if you were only ever going to work with files.

In your case, where you *need* to work with URLs some of the time, it's quite convenient that you can use a file URL and *only* work with URLs.  I imagine you've abstracted nearly all of the interesting logic to work on URLs and can do the ugly business of constructing a file or non-file URL elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed technical answer on how it works underneath the hood! Yes the module is is currently set to accept URLs so it doesn't need to know where the file resides.

Answer (score 0):

A FileInputStream obtains input bytes from a file in a file system. FileInputStream is meant for reading streams of raw bytes such as image data.

FileReader is meant for reading streams of characters.

In general, creating a connection to a URL is a multistep process:

1. The connection object is created by invoking the openConnection method on a URL.
2. The setup parameters and general request properties are manipulated.
3. The actual connection to the remote object is made, using the connect method.
4. The remote object becomes available. The header fields and the contents of the remote object can be accessed.

I think a good rule of thumb is to use the simplest code (object) possible in order to remain the most efficient.  Think minimalist!

P.S. Not sure if you're just moving the file or reading its contents.

Comment: Agreed about the minimalist idea. The thing is the resource is selected high up the stack so instead of wrapping passing some meta info on the type of resource down the stack, changing it to a URL and sending it down the stack to the code would be simpler.